# Best testing tool for browser certification testing

Tags: testing, cross-browser, automated-tests, ui-testing

please help me to get rid of this. I have a web application and i need to develop automated scripts to cross verify that all the required components/elements are rendering fine on the web pages across different browsers. i simply shouuld say that this is UI testing. so please suggest me the best automation tool which can be a open source or a paid version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go for Selenium (open source) if you have basic coding knowledge in any one of the following languages (C, Java , C#, Groovy, Perl, PHP, Python and Ruby) or QTP (Paid) which has good Record and Play . Just google the differences between the two and choose the one which sets well for your web application .